# How to delete or remove the recent documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I use Word 2007. There are documents I do not want to be shown in the `recent documents` list:

[image: word recent documents list]

How to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the File menu (or Office button), and select Options. Click `Advanced`. Set `Show this number of Recent Documents box` to 0

(See also: [How to clear the list of recently used files in 2007 Office programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/926535))